# Rails form builder unexpectedly closes the form tag when used within tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Form builder behaves unexpectedly when building a form within a table. It closes the form immediately.

Yes, I know that tables are generally bad. But in this case, I'm displaying line items for billing purposes, which is a pretty good use case for tables.

Each row is designed to be its own form that auto-submits on change.

[image: This image explains what is going on]

[View Source](https://github.com/protolif/rustic/blob/rails4/app/views/labors/index.html.haml#L16)

I'm not sure if this is by design in Rails, or if it's a bug.

I get the whole opinionated software thing, but this behavior is a little extreme.

I promise that there are no bombs in my shoes. The framework should let me do what I want, even if you think it's stupid.

At this point I'm ready to copypasta the raw HTML myself. But, I really shouldn't have to.

What do you guys think (if that's not too gender normative)?

Comment: I bet if I used nested tables it would work. Trying...

Comment: It works, but the cells don't line up with the corresponding THs.

Comment: I suppose I could make divs that emulate tables. /sigh

Answer (score 0):

Your tool is acting correctly in this case, you are asking it to create a form under a tr.. when you should encase it in a th like you have for the Service, notes, and cost..

in short you can not have a "<%= form_for" directly under a tr.. move it into a th

Comment: I understand **why** it's closing the form tag. I just don't think that it should. It goes against Ruby's core principle of freedom. I should be free to bend the rules. See also: monkey patching

Comment: So basically, you think your tool should allow you to write invalid html?  This has nothing to do with Ruby and/or monkey patching.  This is entirely the way the tool has been implemented

Comment: Yes. It should allow me to write invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think the HTML generated by Rails would be the one you expect, it is the browser which parses the HTML which is having trouble with it. You can check that by using `View Page Source` instead of using `Inspect Element` to view the HTML generated.

My guess is the HTML from the view source would be something along the lines of:

```
<form class="submitless" action="/tickets/1294/labors/1090" method="post">
  <td class="service">
    <select>...</select>
    ...
  </td>
</form>
```

But since this is not valid HTML, the browser might be having a hard time understanding it and is parsing it wrongly.